# Using regexmatch to count the number times certain text appears

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, sum, array-formulas

Bit of a Sheets noob here.

I have data on products and their quantity but they are all in one cell together (e.g. 1x Product A, 2x Product B, etc). How do I use regexmatch to sum the value of the products automatically? So if Product A = $5 and Product B = $1, and if cell B2 has '1x A, 2x B' I want it to sum 5+2. Most products are sold in 1s or 2s so I realise I will have to manually enter ín the formula '1x A' to equal to 5, and '2x A' to equal to 10, etc, but I just want to know if there is a way to enter this all into a single formula because at the moment I only know how to do it individually: 
`=if(regexmatch(B2, "1x A"), 5, 0)`

Or, is there a way for the formula just to output the quantity that '1x A' etc appears in column B? So if I have 20 rows of data, and in those rows '1x A' appears 15 times, '2x A' appears 2 times and '1x B' appears 4 times and '2x B' appears 3 times, can it output '17' to a cell that tallies product A, and '7' to another cell that tallies product B? Then I could just have another cell with a formula that multiplies those numbers by the price of each product.

Or should I use something like `=COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B, REGEXMATCH(B2:B, "1x A")))`  for this? So if Column B has 2 counts of '1x A' and 1 count of '2x A' I want a formula that will output '4'. I just don't know how to sum the value of multiple `COUNTA`s in a single formula.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: As ever, please share a link to your sheet or a copy of your sheet (or a sample sheet with realistic representative data). When sharing the link, be sure to set the permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." We have to be able to see and access the actual data that you can see and access to suggest formula solutions effectively and efficiently.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,MMULT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")), "^\d+"))*
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")), "^\d+x ?(.+)"), E:F, 2, 0)), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))))^0)))
```

[image]